# Two charged free particles with the same energy coming toward each other. What will be the time-dependent perturbation in this case?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, hamiltonian, perturbation-theory, scattering-cross-section

Let's assume we have two charged free particles with the same energy coming toward each other. What will be the time-dependent perturbation in this case? More precisely, I am asking what will be the change in Hamiltonian due to which perturbation is happening? Is it the Columbian potential only which will change? If yes, then how will it change as a function of time? Am I missing something very basic here? To provide more context to this question, I am trying to figure out how the Hamiltonian changes in a muon production process through electron-positron scattering. That is The form of scattering amplitude M .